# Hiding Facebook Messenger customer chat on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've installed the facebook chat icon on my website [www.magnify.mx](http://magnify.mx) but i wish  to have it show only on desktop and be hidden in phones and tablets. Is there a way to have it **not show on mobile**? A code line I can add?

Here's the code

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  greeting_dialog_display="hide"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="1663984783903917"
  theme_color="#000000"
  logged_in_greeting="¡Hola! ¿En qué podemos ayudarte?"
  logged_out_greeting="¡Hola! ¿En qué podemos ayudarte?">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .fb-customerchat{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

or you can check width of the screen in script as follows

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   if(document.body.clientWidth<769) return;
   ...
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>`
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply!! Sorry, is that to be insterted before the facebook code or after?

Comment: Thank you @japesh singhal . Sadly it is still showing up, I've tried adding both solutions before the start of the code, right here

-----solution here------

`code`
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

.....


am I doing something wrong?

Comment: <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   if(document.body.clientWidth<769) return;
   
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
implement it in above way
In the first solution have you defined the media query  properly because it was working fine on my machine